# How to configure scope of information I gather from Google OAuth in MeteorJS package?

Tags: oauth, meteor, google-oauth

Tried searching google and StackOverflow but with no luck, perhaps your knowledge of Google-OAuth can help...

I installed the base google-oauth package via meteor.

```
meteor add accounts-ui
meteor add accounts-google
```

Then I tested it out and saw that it requests the user to permit access to 2 main groups on information, the first being the user's email and the second being "basic information" about the users account, e.g. Name, Gender, Public Profile URL etc etc.

I **only** want the **email** and no other information. I tried to look for where the URI request is built in my meteor app, someurlprobablygoogle.com/scope=email&profile or whatever, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To configure Google OAuth in Meteor you need to `meteor add service-configuration` and `meteor add accounts-google`.

You should be able to modify the `requestPermissions` setting when calling your login method like so:

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
 requestPermissions: ['email']
}, function (err) {
  if (err)
  Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
});
```

Shooooots

Comment: Do you have a list somewhere of the token we can add in the `requestPermissions` array ?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for the Facebook login? To adjust the scope parameter?

Comment: @PredragStojadinović yes. Same syntax, but with `Meteor.loginWithFacebook`. The list of facebook permissions (~=scopes) is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions). Also note that if you're using the `accounts-ui` package you can configure permissions without touching directly the `Meteor.loginWith` method. Just provide `Accounts.ui.config` with the configuration options that are shown [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config) in Meteor docs